# Change primary key with inheritance by redefining field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible to explicitly specify the primary key of a table to an existing field when using inheritance?

```
class TemporalModel(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField() # This is normally not a primary key

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Temperatures(TemporalModel):
    time = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True) # I want it to be a primary key for this model
```

As it happens, the Temperatures 'table' is actually a view, so what I set the primary key to is irrelevant (as far as I know? - my understanding is that this should be okay as long as django doesn't verify any uniqueness constraints itself, but rather leaves it to the database); it's just important that django doesn't try to access .id on the table.  I've thus got a workaround, but I'm curious whether you can do this at all.